# How to ignore file or folder history managed for git?

Tags: git

I have many cache files in my project to use in unit tests and because of this my .git folder has 3 GB and increasing.

Edit.

I don't want ignore the files, but the history are is not important, my objective is reduce the .git folder

Comment: Assuming your question here is how to ignore those files?  Have you checked out the .gitignore file?  And then deleting the files from the repo so they don't remain there?

Comment: it is unclear what is your problem! `.gitignore` file doesn't do that job?

Comment: You should consider using git-lfs (large file storage) : https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: The files aren't large but many

Answer (score 0):

Remove files from the working tree and from the index

[View the command options used](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)

```
git rm -r -n --cached file or directory
git rm -r --cached file
// Add these files or directories to the .gitignore file
// commit and push to warehouse
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file in your local repository called `.gitignore` that lists which files, file types, and paths you want to ignore when uploading to a remote repository.

For example, to exclude all files ending with `.file`, you can add `*.file`. If you want to exclude all instances of a directory, you can add `folder/`.

EDIT:
If you want to purge a file from the commit history, you can use the `git filter-branch` command or the BFG Repo-Cleaner, although these tools are intended mostly for hiding files with sensitive information.

References:

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore

https://github.com/github/gitignore

Purging files from history:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

Comment: I don't want to ignore the cache files in repository, but only history